# Why do almost all ZeroMQ code samples contain sleep() operations?

Tags: zeromq, distributed-computing

I'm learning ZeroMQ and trying to build a simple message queue in Python.

I noticed basically all code samples contain some kind of `sleep()` operation.

Even the [hello world](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:hwserver) example on the ZeroMQ guide does, with the comment `"Do some work"`.

I find this a little unclear, is the motivation to simulate the act of processing the message? Why is this necessary?

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

while True:
    #  Wait for next request from client
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received request: %s" % message)

    #  Do some 'work'
    time.sleep(1)

    #  Send reply back to client
    socket.send(b"World")
```

Comment: you can remove the sleep statement from this code.  the only issue you have to be careful about is the "slow joiner" issue, but I don't think that affects reply/request

Answer (score 1):

> *is the motivation to simulate the act of processing the message ?*

Sort of yes. Launching **`while True:`** "without" any ***handbrake*** would be soon pretty ugly on screen with a literally endlessly running river of `print()`-s, wouldn't it?

> *Why is this necessary ?*

Just a cheap SLOC / convenience-trick. Except for cases, where some latency needs to get injected, there is no technical reason for **`sleep()`**-s